Is this (or any arbitrary) algebraic variety an orbifold?
Inspired by this question zero  set of  polynomial is  irreducible  without algebraic  geometry the  following  question came to me. First note that usually a singular algebraic  variety is not a  manifold where problematic points  are  singularities. On the other hand orbifolds are generalization of  manifolds  so  the  question is the  following:

Is the real  or  complex  variety $z_1z_2=z_3^2$   an orbifold? If the  answer is yes  what about arbitrary algebraic  variety?


I don't really know what an orbifold is, but nevertheless your example variety certainly is one: the map $K^2 \rightarrow K^3$ defined by $(x,y) \mapsto (x^2,y^2,xy)$ exhibits your variety as a $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$-quotient of the affine plane.

@LazzaroCampeotti  Yes thank you. that is q complete answer about that particular variety. Orbifolds are locally looks the quotient of Euclideqn open sets by finitw group. But what about arbitrary irreducible varitey

@LazzaroCampeotti As you see in the linked post I was aware if 2 covering sheet but I did nit pay attention that it is indeed an orbufold structure. So your answer is interesting.But I wonder if every irreduxible curve is qn orbifold?

@LazzaroCampeotti  May be $symmetries of qlgebraic vaieties" is a related subject?(for orbifold structure on irreducible curves"?

$z_1z_2=0$ is not an orbifold, because at any point $p$ on any orbifold $\mathcal O$ there is a neighorhood basis of $p$ consisting of sets $U \subset \mathcal O$ such that $U-p$ is connected.

Thank  you  and  +1  what  about irreducible  variety? In particular the example considered in the post

Is the  question obvious  or  already  studied  for  arbitrary irreducible  variety?

I don't have an irreducible counterexample at hand, but the answer seems to me obviously no. The particular local topological singularities at orbifold points are SO special (i.e. cones on spherical orbifolds) that I would be astonished if every singular point of an irreducible variety has such a neighborhood. Perhaps something as simple as constructing an irreducible variety with a singularity which is a cone on a Euclidean orbifold might do for a counterexample.
